# iTunes: use same folder by Mac and Windows

Tags: windows, macos, itunes, boot-camp, paragon

I have Windows 8 installed on my MacBook Pro with Boot Camp, and I have read/write access to my HFS+ partition through Paragon's HFS+ for Windows 10. My question is, can I install iTunes on Windows and point it to the iTunes Media folder on the Mac partition?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: Yes, but you should be careful. If you point your library to the folder that contains the OSX-iTunes Library, you can easily break your Windows-iTunes Library AND your OSX-iTunes Library.

I'd just open your entire Music Library, stored in your OS X partition, into Windows-iTunes, and keep your Windows-iTunes library pointed to the default folder ("C:\Users\your-username\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media" iirc). You won't see the playlists of the OSX-iTunes, but hey, better than nothing. DO NOT modify anything, you should just create or remove playlists on Windows-iTunes, if you remove songs or so, it may corrupt your OSX-iTunes Library. If you want to add songs to your library, I'd do it from OSX-iTunes, and then, open them in your Windows-iTunes (CTRL+O, for files, ALT -> File -> Add folder to the library, for entire folders).

Greetings